# Display section titles in sidebar as you scroll down page (perhaps with BS scrollspy?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a single page site with an anchor link menu, and I'm trying to figure out how I could take the anchored section title and display it in the sidebar as you scroll down the page to signify where you are in the page. The title would change as you reach different sections.

I'm using bootstrap scrollspy to highlight the active links -- I'm wondering if that can be used with this as well.

To grab the title, I'm using a data attribute like this:

```
<a href="#section1">

...

<div id="section1" data-title="This is my title">
```

And then I'm using jQuery to display the title in the sidebar label:

```
var title = $('#section1').attr("data-title")
$('#label span').html(title)
```

What I can't figure out is how to change that title as you scroll down the page.

I've set up a fiddle if you're interested in playing around with it:

https://jsfiddle.net/02uap85b/

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can accomplish this by moving the `data-title` attribute inside the `.nav li > a` and then adding a function fired on the `activate.bs.scrollspy` event.

```
$(".nav").on("activate.bs.scrollspy", function(){
    var currentItem = $(".nav li.active > a").text();
    $('#label span').empty().html(currentItem);
})
```

based on [these tutorials](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-scrollspy.php), in particular see [this example](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=scrollspy-activate-event).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

// display section 1 title in sidebar

  





// smooth scrolling
$(function() {
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
   if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
     var target = $(this.hash);
     target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
     if (target.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
     }
   }
    });
  });
    
    $(".nav").on("activate.bs.scrollspy", function(){
        var currentItem = $(".nav li.active > a").text();
        $('#label span').empty().html(currentItem);
    })
    
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-right: 60px
}

header {
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: background-color .45s ease-in-out, width .5s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1) 0ms, transform 1s cubic-bezier(.25, .46, .45, .94), opacity .6s linear .8s, -webkit-opacity .6s linear .8s;
}

header:hover {
  width: 33vw;
  transition: background-color .45s ease-in-out, width .5s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1) 0ms, transform 1s cubic-bezier(.25, .46, .45, .94), opacity .6s linear .8s, -webkit-opacity .6s linear .8s;
}

.navbar-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0
}

.navbar-toggle {
  display: block!important;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px 5px;
  width: 60px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background: black;
  margin: 0 auto
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s
}

header:hover #menu {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s
}

#menu li.active a:after {
  content: ' /'
}

header .bug {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 60px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 500
}

#label {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  animation-delay: 1s
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin-top: 0
}

#label > span {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.section {
  position: relative
}

#section0 {
  background-image: url(http://a3.files.blazepress.com/image/upload/MTI4OTgzNTM2OTg3MzE0NjU0.gif);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: #fff;
}

#section1 {
  background: #3498db
}

#section2 {
  background-image: url(http://a3.files.blazepress.com/image/upload/MTI4OTgzNTM2OTg3MzE0NjU0.gif);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: #fff;
}

#section3 {
  background: #973456
}

.panel {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.section .panel:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red
}

.section .panel:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: green
}

.section .panel:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: blue
}

.section .panel:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: purple
}

.banner {
  padding: 120px 0
}

.flyout {
  right: -99999px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}

.section .panel:hover > .flyout {
  right: 0;
  top: 0
}

.logo {
  margin: 25px 0
}

.heading {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 60px 15px
}

.bottom {
  bottom: 0
}

.left {
  left: 0
}

.right {
  right: 0
}

.top {
  top: 0
}

.full {
  height: 100vh;
}

.full > .container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0
}

.goingdown {
  font-size: 42px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none
}

.text-white {
  color: #fff
}

.text-black {
  color: #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#menu">

  <header class="animated fadeInUp">


    <div id="label" class="animated fadeIn">
      <span>Title Goes Here</span>
    </div>

    <nav id="menu">

      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#section0" data-title="Section 0 Title">Section 0</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section1" data-title="Section 1 Title">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2" data-title="This is Section 2">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3" data-title="Welcome to Section 3">Section 3</a></li>
      </ul>

    </nav>


  </header>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="section full" id="section0">

      <div class="container text-center">


        <div class="heading">
          <h1>Welcome to Section 0</h1>
          
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="section banner" id="section1">

      <div class="container text-center text-white">

        <h1>This is Section 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ipsum velit, bibendum nec tellus et, facilisis vehicula est. Curabitur imperdiet, lectus vel condimentum luctus, nunc lacus sagittis augue, viverra auctor lacus justo nec nisi. Sed
          maximus nulla eget ultrices posuere. Duis sodales ultricies augue ac pulvinar. Vivamus vitae metus tempor, cursus lectus vel, eleifend enim. Duis non quam vitae lacus elementum ultrices. Etiam condimentum odio justo, sit amet ultrices metus
          dapibus non. Pellentesque sodales risus eget dui euismod, euismod tincidunt nisi accumsan. Pellentesque malesuada, lectus in ultrices blandit, purus tortor consectetur risus, vitae egestas felis magna quis turpis. Donec blandit sed sapien et
          commodo.
        </p>



      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="section banner full" id="section2">

      <div class="container wow fadeIn text-center text-white">

        <h1>And This is Section 2</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ipsum velit, bibendum nec tellus et, facilisis vehicula est. Curabitur imperdiet, lectus vel condimentum luctus, nunc lacus sagittis augue, viverra auctor lacus justo nec nisi. Sed
          maximus nulla eget ultrices posuere. Duis sodales ultricies augue ac pulvinar. Vivamus vitae metus tempor, cursus lectus vel, eleifend enim. Duis non quam vitae lacus elementum ultrices. Etiam condimentum odio justo, sit amet ultrices metus
          dapibus non. Pellentesque sodales risus eget dui euismod, euismod tincidunt nisi accumsan. Pellentesque malesuada, lectus in ultrices blandit, purus tortor consectetur risus, vitae egestas felis magna quis turpis. Donec blandit sed sapien et
          commodo.
        </p>



      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section full" id="section3">


      <h1>Hey! Section Three!</h1>


    </div>



  </div>
```

here's the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02uap85b/1/)